# How can I deploy a JavaScript game into the iOS app store?

Tags: javascript, ios, html5, appstore

Unfortunately, I don't have a Mac, so I can't develop for iOS.

I understand that HTML5 apps run in the browser, but is there a way to make an HTML5 app (e.g. a JavaScript game) and get it deployed onto the app store through Apple? How should I package and submit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this: http://blog.forecast.io/its-not-a-web-app-its-an-app-you-install-from-the-web/

Deploy your web app and provide an easy way for the user to make it a web clip.

Comment: hmm this looks really interesting. thanks for the answer

Comment: it's a good solution but i downvoted because it doesn't solve the problem ('onto the app store')

Comment: the link jumps to an inexistent page :(

Answer (score 14):

Yes. There are many ways to wrap an HTML5 game for distribution on iOS. Solutions include [CocoonJS](http://www.ludei.com/tech/cocoonjs), [Game Closure](http://www.gameclosure.com/), [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), and [Ejecta](http://impactjs.com/ejecta).

Examples of HTML5 games on iOS include [Onslaught! on iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onslaught!/id441426241) and [Biolab Disaster on iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/biolab-disaster/id433062854?mt=8).

Comment: I also thought of PhoneGap immediately when I saw the question title, but upon reading the first sentence I saw that wouldn't help him. He doesn't have a Mac, so he can't use any sort of packaging framework; he's asking about literally just HTML5 and nothing else.

Comment: @jhocking There is a way without a Mac by using the [PhoneGap online build system](https://build.phonegap.com/).

Comment: well I did not know about that, cool

Comment: @richtaur Is it possible, using Game Closure, to deploy to iOS without a Mac? I thought it would be only possible to deploy to Android. Can you provide a link please?

Answer (score 1):

Well as previous answer says, PhoneGap is a solution. Even if he doesn't have mac. PhoneGap hhas own build system

Comment: Hi and welcome! This does add extra info, but isn't really an answer to the question. You can comment on other people's posts once you have enough reputation.